# Using Rails.application.routes.recognize_path inside middleware breaks the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

The next middleware causes Rails app to fail loading assets

```
class Wtf
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    # next line is causing all troubles
    Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.path
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

if i replace the problem line with

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path '/'
```

then everything works again.

How come that sending `request.path` as the argument to the `recognize_path` can cause app to be unable to load assets?

The app can be found here https://github.com/mib32/wtf-middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails asset pipeline compiles assets under the hashed paths you can see in the request, and those are handled differently than your other routing, so `recognize_path` won't behave properly. If you don't need your middleware to be messing with assets, you should skip these paths.

```
unless request.path =~ %r(^/assets/)
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.path
end
```

Or,

```
begin
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.path
rescue ActionController::RoutingError
  # pass
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried it yet but it definately makes sense.